# HotTowel - unable to upgrade to webapi 2 (vs2013)

Tags: hottowel, asp.net-web-api2

I have upgraded to Visual Studio 2013, and naturally I wanted to upgrade HotTowel, Breeze and all the other friends to also support MVC5, WebApi2, EF6 etc.

After a lot of back and forth, I have managed to update to WebApi2 and Breeze for WebApi2 + EF6. But HotTowel struggles.

I am unable to get HotTowel back, because it kicks in the Package Manager Console with the message:
install-package : Already referencing a newer version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi'

What does that mean? On the nuget page it says that it depends on: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi (≥ 4.0.30506.0). My version of webapi is 5.x.x which is over the required 4.0xx.

Can anyone help me get HotTowel back?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it all depends on where you are now. I suggest removing the packages and dll's and starting fresh. Start with a clean project and `install-package hottowel.angular`.  If you want to try to piecemeal it together, it can work but it may be more painful.

If you started with the older hottowel, asp.net web api 2 broke it. SO the newest one uses the latest features. If you want web api v2, use `hottowel.angular.breeze`.

The issue is not HotTowel, its the incompat with Web Api 2 and some other MSFT features.

For more details, see this link: http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel-angular-and-asp-net-web-api-2-compat/

Comment: The problem with this is that I am not using angular. I am using knockout and breeze. How will this sit with my existing code?

Comment: There are some new Breeze and asp.net web api 2 nuget packages that you will need. Breeze. 1.4.5, for example. Breeze.Client (≥ 1.4.5)
Breeze.Server.WebApi2 (≥ 1.4.5)

Comment: I already had a project using all of this, so I had to uninstall HotTowel and add in all required Nuget packages myself to get up and running again. It was a pain to get up, but now I have full control of all package updates myself.
I really appreciate your HotTowel solution regardless of these latest upgrade issues. It was a very, very good starting point for someone who had never created a SPA before. And now, I am probably one of the best in the world at it... ;-)